# Two equal IPv6 IPAddress instances return different GetHashCode results

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address, gethashcode

I have two clients that create `IPAddress` instances from the **same** `byte[]` and send it to the server over WCF (using `DataContractSerializer`).

On the server, these `IPAddress` instances are inserted as keys in a dictionary but for some reason they're added as different keys.

When logging I see that they're equal but `GetHashCode` returns different results.

```
var client1Address = // sent from client1
var client2Address = // sent from client2

Console.WriteLine(client1Address.Equals(client2Address));
Console.WriteLine(client1Address.GetHashCode().Equals(client2Address.GetHashCode()));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

How can equal `IPAddress` instances return different `GetHashCode` results?

Answer (score 16):

The [`GetHashCode` implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,a2e59a88870e1017,references) of `IPAddress` for IPv6 is:

```
if (m_HashCode == 0)
{
    m_HashCode = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(ToString()); 
    return m_HashCode;
}
```

To avoid recalculating the hash code again and again, they’re storing the result in a private member. This private member is then serialized to the remote server.

The thing is, that `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(ToString())` returns different results on different OS versions, and since `m_HashCode` is serialized as well, the server does not recalculate it.

This results in two identical `IPAddress` instances with different `GetHashCode` results.

I think that the private member `m_HashCode` should be marked as `[NonSerialized]`, that will cause `GetHashCode` to re-generate the hash code locally and correctly.

As a workaround, I interfered in the serialization process and serialized as a `byte[]`.

---

[Here's the bug on VisualStudio connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1125300). This link is dead as the bug was closed for these reasons:

> "Thank you for reporting this issue. Unfortunately, our team is not able to address this issue due to other, higher priority items. Further, any changes to the serialized content of a type result in a risk of breaking apps that have taken a dependency on that behavior. "

Comment: I believe this exact scenario is warned about in .NET GetHashCode and String Compare and String based Equality operators.   
I do not think this is a bug in that GetHashCode is effectively a private .NET runtime property that should not be directly used by our code at an application level.  
Since IPV6 is a known thing I would use the address itself as the Hash Code or Equality operator.   But I would do the actual compare at the byte level for a formatted value.  Similar to how guid works.  “ABCD-123” = “abcd123”   From A Design Perspective I think it is a bug.  Can they change it now?

Comment: @SqlSurfer `GetHashCode` isn't private and it isn't used directly. When you use `IPAddress` as a dictionary key it uses `GetHashCode` internally. The bug here is that the hash code is cached and serialized when it shouldn't be.